# Banno API can it list internal users and their permissions?

Tags: banno-digital-toolkit

From reading the api docs, I really can't tell. Does the banno Admin api (or any other) have the ability to read a list of bank employees and their access/roles?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Digital Toolkit does not have any APIs which would return info about employees/staff at a financial institution (neither bank nor credit union).

Comment: Thanks Jaime. That's really too bad. We have so many banks using our software that would love to manage users, even if just pull a listing of their roles. Any plans or can banks put in a wish list somehow to get priority with JH?

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Topics related to the _roadmap_ are covered in the _Digital Banking Meetup_, which you can register for at https://www.jackhenry.com/resources/events (and as of this writing, the next session is May 12th).